# how to generate dynamic number array like below

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

```
 $big_box = array(1,2,3,16,17,18,31,32,33,46,47,48,61,62,63,76,77,78,91,92,93,106,107,108,121,122,123,136,137,138............);

 $small_box = array(4,19,34,49,64.............);
```

I want to generate dynamic numbers array like above example upto 10000.

Comment: And the numbers are random? Or is there an order?

Comment: No it will be in same sequence of example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Array `$big_box` Try to something like this.

```
       $j = 0;
       for ($i=0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
            if ($i!=0) {
                $big_box[] = $i;
                $j++;
            }
            if ($j == 3) {
                $j = 1;
                $big_box[] = $i+13;
                $i =$i+13;
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($big_box);
```

**And array** `$small_box`

```
        $small_box = array();
        for($i=0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $small_box[$i] = 4;
            }else{
                $small_box[$i] = $small_box[$i-1]+15;
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($small_box);
```

Comment: can you please help for $small_box also.

Comment: I have upload both. Please check

Comment: Thanks mota bhai :)